Autodesk Construction Cloud Docs : DWF files 2D views no longer display properties
Any 2D views in any multi-view dwf file uploaded no longer display any object property in the viewer after migration to svf2. This only affects multi-view dwf files.

To assist you more effectively in resolving this issue, could you please share a demo model that reproduces the problem? Screenshots highlighting the issue would also be helpful for clarity. Kindly email the requested details to aps.help@autodesk.com.
